# How to make two sets of axis labels in grouped line graph in dimple.js?

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

In the example here,

http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=lines_horizontal_grouped_stacked

How can I add x-labels of month, like just above "Black Mesa" and "Aperture"?

Answer (score 0):

You can just verify the previous example which was already solved for two X-axis labels and the URL is:

[Dual X-axes for line Graphs using SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233847/dual-x-axes-for-line-graphs-in-svg)

and also you can just add two CategoryAxis which is much simple such that:

```
myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Month"); 
myChart.addCategoryAxis("x","Owner");
```