# d3 Axis Bottom with Padding

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I want to display two xAxis at the bottom of my graph, one placed above the other. Hence in order to have my axes at the bottom, I specified `.orient('bottom')` on both x1Axis and x2Axis.
Moreover, I set the `transform` property to `translate(0, height)` as can be seen below:

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x1 axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(x1Axis);

for(var i = 0 ; i < x1domain.length; i++){
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x2 axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate("+ (x1.rangeBand()*i*(1/(1-x1padding))+ x1(x1domain[0])) + "," + height + ")")
      .call(x2Axis);
}
```

As expected, I ended up with both axes superposing like so: 
[image: Not the pinnacle of readability, huh]

Hence I modified x1Axis's transform property to `translate(0, height-x)` to move the axis up a bit. No matter the value of x (attempted {x | 1 <= x <= 20 } ), I was surprised to always obtain the following result:

[image: Not quite there yet.]

Hence my question is, how can I have both axes at the bottom and one above the other? The behaviour seems to be predefined to clipping to top or bottom.

**Note:** For the sake of this discussion, ignore the fact that I am printing several axes for my x2Axis.

Comment: I don't find anything surprising here on one of the axis you are doing `translate(0, height-x)` so the axis has moved up.
Doing translate will move the axis accordingly.

Comment: Well that would be the expected behaviour if I wrote `translate(0, height-height)` but in this case `translate(0, height-1)` yields the same result

Comment: And what is the value of `x`? As if it's greater than `height`, you'll get negative `translate's` second coordinate ie `translate(0, -200)`.

Comment: In this case I tried { x | 1 <= x <= 20 } and height is 250

Comment: This modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kd8kd9u/) from this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233847/dual-x-axes-for-line-graphs-in-svg) reproduces the same behaviour. `xAxis2` is oriented to the bottom on line 28 and the translate property of the group is set on line 80. You'll observe the same behaviour as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around, I found out that the reason why putting `height - 1` resulted in the second axis going to the top. The reason was that Javascript would try to type cast the start of the string to a number due to the presence of a minus sign and then add it to the `height - 1`, resulting in `NaN` as the value of the transform property.

Hence, from

`.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height-1 + ")")`

I changed it to

`.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height-1) + ")")`

solving the type casting issue with the extra parentheses around `height-1`.